# Range queries in Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

I have two fields in my ES index: `min_duration` and `max_duration`. I want to create a query to find all the documents for input `duration` such that :

`min_duration<=duration<=max_duration`

For example if `duration` is 30 seconds then I should get all docs having `min_duration` less than eq to `duration` and `duration` less than eq to `max_duration`.

I am using ES Java API and seems like range filter is the way to go. I have constructed the range filter as follows:

```
val filter = FilterBuilders.andFilter( FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("min_duration").lte(duration),FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("max_duration").gte(duration))
```

Though it still not seems to work for me. Is it the correct way to build this type of query or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing it with [bool query](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/java-api/query-dsl/bool-query.asciidoc). Wrap your two range clauses inside it like

```
QueryBuilder qb = boolQuery()
    .must(rangeQuery("max_duration").gte(duration))
    .must(rangeQuery("min_duration").lte(duration));
```

Does this help?